# PostgresSQL - how to design an effective table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I need to collect data from tens of sensors, with are saving data in 15s interval, in postgres database and want that select with values from last month/week/day were run fast - to draw charts.
What indexes, partitions or other things I should use?

```
CREATE TABLE temperatures(
  sensor_id integer NOT NULL,
  val real NOT NULL,
  audit_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
)
```

Comment: Would creating materialized views using the filters you need be an option for you?

Comment: I think yes - charts are creating in php and js so queries should only give data ordered by audit_date

Comment: You have to tell us the queries if you want index recommendations.

Comment: queries:    select 
  s.sensor_id,
  audit_date::timestamp(0) as audit_date,
  t.val,
  s.comment
 from 
  temperatures t, 
  sensors s
 where 
  t.audit_date >= timestamp '$date1'
  and t.audit_date <= timestamp '$date2'
  and t.sensor_id in (select sensor_id from users_sensors us, users u where us.user_id = u.user_id and u.login = '$login')
  and t.sensor_id = s.sensor_id
 order by 2`

Answer (score 2):

For each sensor, you are collecting 5,760 rows per day.  That can start to add up.

First, I would suggest partitioning the data.  The right way to partition the data depends on how you really intend to use it.  You mention returning the most recent data, so that definitely suggests using time.  You might also want to include the `sensor_id` as a partitioning key, but that is less likely.  You can start learning about partitioning in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html).

Next you want indexes.  Presumably, you want to fetch values by sensor.  That suggests an index on `(sensor_id, audit_date)`.  However, the index might need to be tweaked to be compatible with the partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 0):

select

```
select 
    s.sensor_id,
    audit_date::timestamp(0) as audit_date,
    t.val,
    s.comment
from 
    temperatures t, 
    sensors s
where 
    t.audit_date >= timestamp '$date1'
    and t.audit_date <= timestamp '$date2'
    and t.sensor_id in (select sensor_id from users_sensors us, users u where us.user_id = u.user_id and u.login = '$login')
    and t.sensor_id = s.sensor_id
order by 2
```